# mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, updates

I have an `SSH` tunnel on my `MySQL` server that points to a another `MySQL` server.

I am upgrading my database drivers in `Codeigniter`. This means that everything worked properly using the `PHP MySQL` divers. After updating my files and changing my connection config array

From:

```
        $config['hostname'] = "127.0.0.1:1111";
        $config['username'] = "user";
        $config['password'] = XXXX;
        $config['database'] = "Mydb";
        $config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

To:

```
        $config['hostname'] = "127.0.0.1:1111";
        $config['username'] = "user";
        $config['password'] = XXXX;
        $config['database'] = "Mydb";
        $config['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

I started getting these errors :

```
 ERROR - 2013-12-24 11:29:37 --> Severity: Warning  --> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:1111' (0) /var/www/app/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php 110
 ERROR - 2013-12-24 11:29:37 --> Unable to connect to the database
```

When I revert back to `$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";` it works again, so the files are fine.

Is `MySQLi` drivers unable to connect via local tunnel?

How would I go about fixing this? If `MySQLi` unable to connect to a tunnel then how can I update my system?

Note: The local database (127.0.0.1) works fine, its just the tunneled connections that have failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify or supplied your port number as follow,

```
mysqli mysqli_connect ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
```

Syntax:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user","password","database", "3306"); //port is a string!
```

Comment: That's the case: `$mysqli->real_connect($hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $port, NULL, $client_flags)`

Comment: and when I attempt `mysqli_connect('local......` or `new mysqli('local......` i get an error `Message: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` I'm pretty sure that its due to the fact that it's trying to connect to the local database and it has a different password...